# How to "overload" templated alias declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, using, type-alias

I want to create a type alias `array_t`. It should work for both bounded and unbounded arrays. I can declare it for each case separately like this:

```cpp
// Type of an unbounded array of `T`
template <typename T>
using array_t = T[];
// Type of an array of `T` of size `Size`
template <typename T, size_t Size>
using array_t = T[Size];
```

The problem is that both cannot be declared at the same time. I think that the solution could be to use some kind of template specialization, but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: how you decide to use them?

Comment: What do you need this type-alias for? What is the actual problem it's supposed to solve?

Comment: @appleapple I am not planning to use `array_t`, I gave it as a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve - "overload" an alias declaration. I could have provided a more complex example, but this one shows the intention.

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr... please do provide a more complex example, you cannot even overload normal class definition this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

> It is not possible to partially or explicitly specialize an alias template.

However, it is possible to use non-type template parameter pack so we can use the following trick:

```cpp
template <class T, size_t... Sizes>
struct array_t_helper 
{ };

template <class T, size_t Size>
struct array_t_helper<T, Size>
{
    using t = T[Size];
};

template <class T>
struct array_t_helper<T>
{
    using t = T[];
};

template <typename T, size_t... Sizes>
using array_t = typename array_t_helper<T, Sizes...>::t;
```

Comment: Awesome, clever trick! Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: I would just change the primary template to not define `t` at all, because having it being `void` could potentially cause some issues, while not having it defined would be SFINAE-friendlier.